# C++ Beginner Stuck

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int score;
  cout << "Enter your score (0-100): ";
  cin >> score;

  if (score >= 90 && score <= 100){
      cout << "You have earned an A" + (score);
  }else if(score >= 80 && score <= 89) {
      cout << "You have earned a B" + (score);
  }else if(score >= 70 && score <= 79) {
      cout << "You have earned a C" + (score);
  }else if(score >= 60 && score <= 69) {
      cout << "You have earned a D" + (score);
  }else if(score >= 0 && score <= 59) {
      cout << "You have earned a F" + (score);
  }


  return 0;
}
```

When I run the program the output does not work. Instructions were to write a program that asks the user to enter the score (0-100) obtained in some exam (for simplicity, please assume only integer values are allowed) and print the letter grade corresponding to the score, assuming the scale shown below:

90-100 → A

80-89 → B

70-79 → C

60-69 → D

Below 60 → F

Comment: The core language string literals are not beginner-friendly. Well, they're not friendly at all, to anyone, but. You can't convert to string and concatenate the way you do in e.g. JavaScript. Instead write e.g. `cout << "You have earned an A with your score of " << score`.

Comment: In those cases where you do need a single string value you can convert to `std::string` by including the `<string>` header and writing e.g. `to_string( score ) `. The resulting `std::string` can be concatenated with other `std::string`s as well as core language string literals, via just `+`.

Comment: Off topic: You can simplify your code by starting with a check of `score` being in the valid range - see https://ideone.com/7QTFUl

Comment: *"the output does not work"* is not exactly a search-engine-friendly description of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are a java developer,
To print a string and a variable value, in java we use,

```
System.out.print("Value of a is:" + a);
```

We use '+' operator for string concatination.
But in C++ we can write as,

```
cout<<"Value of a is:"<<a;
```

So in your code replace all the '+' with '<<' (Insertion operator) in your printing statement.

For more reference visit: [cout reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/)